# Can generators of a Coxeter group be redundant?

Tags: abstract-algebra, coxeter-groups

I’m just beginning to learn about Coxeter groups and at one point the textbook’s author seems to take it for grant that each generator cannot be “reduced” into a product of other generators. Specifically, it seems the following claim is so obvious that it need not be stated:

If $\{s_1, s_2,..., s_n\}$ is the set of generators of a coxeter group $W$, then one cannot have $s_i=s_1s_2...s_{j-1}s_js_{j-1}...s_1$ for some $j$ without $i, j$ being $1$.

So I suspected something like $s_1=s_2s_4s_8$ cannot happen too. I know the question looks really stupid but it seems I’m missing something fundamental.

Comment: This is not obvious -- I suspect it only becomes clear somewhere in Chapter 4 of [Björner/Brenti](https://www.doi.org/10.1007/3-540-27596-7), not earlier. The easiest way to see the claim is if you know that the length function of a parabolic subgroup $W_I$ of $W$ is the restriction of the length function of $W$ (see, e.g., §9.6 of [arXiv:math/0208154v2](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0208154v2)); thus, if $s_i$ was a product of other $s_j$'s, then $s_i$ would have to be a **single** other $s_j$, which would contradict the (nontrivial) fact that the elements of $S$ are distinct in $W$.